# Remove a custom folder containing a Windows folder tree

Tags: windows-8, file-permissions

I have a folder sitting in my C: drive in Win8 that I can't delete using rd from an elevated prompt as it says I don't have the rights to do so (it is a folder which contains the folder structure of a Win7 system partition.)

Also, I have just a single recovery point and it's not prior to the problem and I can't have enough space on disk to make a system "refresh" until I remove this folder (it takes about 10/50GB and the rest is mostly system files or files I can't easily backup.)

further details here if needed: http://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/282232-test-update-7-installation-media-22.html#post2883688.

Comment: In the end i reinstalled the whole system, but as a reference the problem is about a folder used by DISM to mount an image. (see: http://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/282232-test-update-7-installation-media-22.html#post2883688 and http://superuser.com/questions/811569/inheritable-permissions-checkbox-doesnt-show-up-in-windows-8-gui)

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the folder permission and take the ownership on it, then try again. In worst case you can just boot from a live CD and remove this folder.

Comment: Unfortunately this caomputer is a keyboardable laptop and live CD's are not an options (live USB are also "beyond the scope" difficult).

Comment: [MOVED TO THE COMMENTS OF THE MAIN POST]