# Inheritable permissions checkbox doesn't show up in windows 8 GUI

Tags: windows-8, permissions, cmd.exe

The system language is Chinese but the problem is just as simple as that, no checkbox.

How can I change permissions for the subfolders and the all the conteined files?

[image]

I tried `C:>icacls "C:MyFolder" /grant User:(OI)(CI)F` and `>icacls "C:\MyFolder" /grant Users:(OI)(CI)F` without result.

Comment: the GUI reads "stop using inheritance", so it should be enabled, but it isn't. if I go and manually set permissions for single files I can change it as I please..

Comment: I tried if inheritance worked for a different set of folders and it did. So this a problem with those folders which were created as mounting points by the DISM command. Anyways I reinstalled the whole system..   (refers to: http://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/282232-test-update-7-installation-media-22.html#post2883688 and to http://superuser.com/questions/811536/remove-a-custom-folder-containing-a-windows-folder-tree)